# libpng warning: Interlace handling should be turned on when using png_read_image

Tags: warnings

when I insert a .png figure it show but it didn't cause some troubles.
I juse want to know how can I insert a .png figure without this warning.

```
\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.4\linewidth]{1.png}
    \caption{xxxx}
    \label{fig:transport}
\end{figure}
```

by the way I use XeLatex to complie because of utf-8

Comment: Which texsystem are you using? On which OS?

Comment: TeXStduio  WIN10 64x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a bug of old libpng version (see here for details: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12990602), and should be fixed in the future release of the TeX system or package you are using.

The workaround (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22125146) is to modify the PNG figure to remove the interlace, e.g. using ImageMagick's "convert" utility:
    convert in.png -interlace none out.png